# sendmail mail forward on debian

Tags: email, smtp, debian, sendmail

I'm trying to install sendmail on two computers (debian), the first one is gateway for mails from the second. In other words when you want to send mail from 2nd computer, mail must be send to first computer and then to the world. I have solved problem with forwarding mails from world to 2nd computer by virtusertable. How should i configure sendmail on these computers to make it all work?

im working on virtual box, my domains are virtual, "world" could be third computer linked with first via internal network.

If you want to see any of my configs just let me know.
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: You should ask this question on superUser or serverFault